# How can I override or add new type to a third-party package's type interface?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm using a third-party package where it is perfectly typed and everything is working fine. But due to my project's requirements I have to extend the types illustrated in the package.

Let's say there's an `interface` called Data in the package which looks like this:

```
export interface Data {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    address: string;
}
```

Now I need to add a new type, called `description` in the above interface like this:

```
export interface Data {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    address: string;
    description: string;
}
```

For obvious reasons, it's not right to update the interface directly which is in `node_modules` folder.

Is there a way to add a new type to an interface which already exists in a third-party package?

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#module-augmentation

Comment: @Bergi Hey man. If it's not too much trouble, can you please provide an example based on my situation? I'm not able to wrap my head around Module Implementation and how to implement that in my situation.

Comment: Which package are you trying to amend, what's the code you tried for that, and what error are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

It is simple:

## Step 1

Just create a file named `global.d.ts` in the root of your project. And then just import the 3rd party lib you wanna add more type to its interface. I use an actual example here:

```
import 'keycloak-js';

declare module 'keycloak-js' {
    interface KeycloakTokenParsed {
        'jti': 'f5be5c72-8578-40d9-bc81-53141734591a';
        'typ': 'Bearer';
        'allowed-origins': string[];
        'scope': 'openid profile email';
        'sid': 'e73754b9-2219-46f5-a7b2-8c7d5525c39e';
        'email_verified': boolean;
        'name': string;
        'preferred_username': string;
        'given_name': string;
        'family_name': string;
        'email': string;
    }
}
```

**It is just for my own sake that I used `'f5be5c72-8578-40d9-bc81-53141734591a'` instead of string. So please do not mind me and go with string if you like. BTW I could also use JSDoc and use `string` as well.

## Second step

There you have it [image]

## Github repo

https://github.com/kasir-barati/you-say